# gx:Track icon quickly appears then disappears at the origin when timeline is up. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have researched this exhaustively and still haven't found a solution.  When I have multiple tracks (cars on roads) in google earth, when a track ends the icon will quickly appear then disappear (flash) at the origin location.  This gets very very distracting when I have hundreds of tracks displayed at the same time.  I am attaching an example kmz, notice that once a track completes the icon flashes at the origin.

Does anyone know how to solve the issue so that the icon does not flash at the origin when the track is complete?

Thanks for any help you can offer, this is driving me crazy.

sample KMZ file showing the problem: https://groups.google.com/group/kml-support-advanced/attach/5d1ba540ca564b13/GoogleEarthPaths.kmz?part=4&authuser=0&view=1

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Google Earth.

I've tested this out on a lot of my existing Tracks that simply use Icons - and I see the same issue.  I had never noticed it before.

However, I tested it out on Tracks that had Model elements defined, and I don't see the "flash" back at the origin of the Track once the Track animation has completed.

I'd recommend putting in a bug report.